# Daily local notifications appears only once - Android

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I made a notifications with some tutorial on Youtube. I thought tha everything is working, because i saw notifications. The problem is when I'm waiting for the notification in next day. It doesn't work. It's not appearing.

Here is a code with hour etc:

```
button1 = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 30);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Notification_receiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

Oh, it's starting working wiith onclick button on my custom dialog which is apear only with first app launch. Please help me guys!

## EDIT

NotificationReceiver java:

```
    package com.justfashion;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationBuilderWithBuilderAccessor;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

/**
 * Created by otsma on 24.11.2016.
 */
public class Notification_receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent repeating_intent = new Intent(context,ActivitySplashScreen.class);
        repeating_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,100,repeating_intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.arrow_up_float)
                .setContentTitle("Hey You!")
                .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName()  + "/" + R.raw.sound))
                .setContentText("Collect today's diamonds!")
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        notificationManager.notify(100,builder.build());


    }





}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Service` class to schedule your notifications. Find the documentation here -[Service | Android Developers](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiCzbekl9DQAhVDtY8KHS3eBbsQFggkMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fguide%2Fcomponents%2Fservices.html&usg=AFQjCNEJmyL4fzjknuW5MHRfZ0mLZ58Juw)

Answer (score 0):

If your app reboots during this period alarm gets cancelled.so no notification on another day.So use broadcast receiver to work around this.And please  do not use service to only show notification.your approach is right.

```
enter code here

    public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {



    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {



        Log.e("BootReceiver","BootReceiver");

        if     (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            // Set the alarm here.



    }

    }



}

   <receiver android:name=".alarmManager.BootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

use permission:

Comment: Add additional receiver :BootReceiver  listen to boot and schedule alarm from there too.

Comment: along with your NotificationReceiver.java  ! and dont forget to add permission : <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

Answer (score 0):

Possible issue with the alarm you have setup 
try this

```
alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

As mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) and [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

Answer (score 0):

Implement this in splash or main screen
This method sets alarm for particular time of day.

```
public void startWeatherAlert() {
        Calendar updateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        updateTime.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
        updateTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);//set hour of day when you want to trigger
        updateTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);//set minute of day

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourReceiverNameHere.class);//Broadcast receiver here
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, updateTime.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);//INTERVAL_DAY means that it will trigger only once in a day.
    }
```

Now setup for broadcast receiver

```
   public class YourReceiverNameHere extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //your logic here
            //this can be used to invoke service, launch activity or to generate notification
        }
    }
```

and finally register that broadcast receiver in menifest

```
<service android:name=".YourReceiverNameHere" />
```